# How to automate BusyBox telnet

Tags: embedded-linux, telnet, busybox

I need an automated telnet script between two embedded Linux targets using BusyBox v1.22.1 on the client and BusyBox v1.10.3 on the host. Note: [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) is not available on this system. I've tried the recommendations [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/shell-script-to-automate-telnet-573950/) without success. For example, this

```
host=1.1.1.2
port=23 # note - port is not required
pass=xxxx # note - pass is not required 
cmd1=24

( echo open ${host} ${port}
  sleep 1
  echo -e "\r"
  sleep 1
  echo ${pass}
  sleep 1
  echo -e "\r"
  sleep 1
  echo ${cmd1}
  sleep 1
  echo -e "\r"
  sleep 1
  echo exit ) | telnet
```

returns this

```
Usage: telnet [-a] [-l USER] HOST [PORT]
Connect to telnet server
        -a      Automatic login with $USER variable
        -l USER Automatic login as USER
```

So I tried various combinations of 'Usage' (above) without success (it always asks for a manually entered 'login').

Is telnet automatic login broken on BusyBox v1.22.1 or am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually got it to work using the original example I pointed to. The confusing part was that the telnet session was exiting without the exit command at the final ")". Also, none of the commands during the telnet session block so the sleep for each command has to be long enough. In this case the 'user' is root and there is no password. I may need to insert a few `echo -e "\r"` but here is the working command that will be incorporated into the script:

```
( echo -e "\r"
  sleep 1
  echo root
  sleep 2
  echo ${cmd1}
  sleep 65
  echo ${cmd2}
  sleep 2
  echo ${cmd3}
  sleep 52 ) | telnet $host
```